# Display shapefiles as layer in map with React 16

Tags: javascript, reactjs, leaflet, gis, react-leaflet

I'm using an old (2 years) leaflet plugin inside react to load a shape file ( a zip file that contains 4 files inside that when displayed on a map will draw a layer, commonly used on GIS)

While the plugin works (tested), I would like to eliminate the upload functionality. just call the zip file that I have inside my app and make it appear and disappear on the layers control menu in the top right of the map. That's it

Here is the https://codesandbox.io/s/34o825nz8m

I believe the trick is in here:

```
  handleFile(e) {

      var reader = new FileReader();

          var file = e.target.files[0];

          reader.onload = function(upload) {

            this.readerLoad(upload);

          }.bind(this);

          reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
    }
```

What I've tried so far:

replaced the var file for './protrac.zip' which is located here (https://www.data.boem.gov/Mapping/Files/protrac.zip)
got an error.

changed reader.readAsDataURL(file).

Since I've erased the input tag my intention is to run the handleFile function inside ComponentDidMount (). but I can't even console.log the zip that I have inside my app.

P.D. if you get a createLeafletElement () error, this can only be fixed on the node_modules folder by putting this line

```
ShapeFile.prototype.createLeafletElement = function createLeafletElement () {}
```